# I have a mysql connection problem, although I connect to the command line with the same parameters

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, localhost

```
 static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
       static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gestionrh";

   //  Database credentials
   static final String USER = "root";
   static final String PASS = "root";
   // connection 
   private Connection conx;

   // requete pour le dialogue
   private Statement stm;

   private void getConnection() {
       try {
        Class.forName(this.JDBC_DRIVER);

        conx = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

        stm = conx.createStatement();

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

   }
```

**here is the Exception**

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for
>   user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)  at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:835)
>     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:455)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:199)
>     at
>   java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
>     at
>   java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:251)
>     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.admin.TimezoneDump.main(TimezoneDump.java:70)

Answer (score 0):

The error says that access denied for root using password **NO**. That means something from the following is incorrect:

1. username
2. password
3. database name

Comment: can you please provide the **command** that you run. @yassine315

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure the username and password is correct. Seems like the database name is wrong or  **gestionrh** doesn't exist.

You can try

```
try {
 Class.forName(this.JDBC_DRIVER);
 conx = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/",USER,PASS);

  stm = conx.createStatement(); 

 String sql = "CREATE DATABASE gestionrh"; 
 stm.executeUpdate(sql);
}
```

Comment: always the same problem, so I'm sure my database

Comment: @yassine315 Can you post screenshot of you connecting via the command line.

Comment: thanks .solved the problem, the problem what I'm compiling another project, sorry

Answer (score 0):

**Avoid using root as user**

create new public user and
grant all pivileges to that user

now replace root by username and the password in your java code.